# Nested Arrays - updating subarrays while nesting with a for loop doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, sub-array

```
const nestedArr = [];
// ADD CODE HERE
let arr = [];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  arr.push(`loop${i}`, i);
  nestedArr.push(arr);
  // nestedArr.push([`loop${i}`, i]);
}

console.log(nestedArr)
```

Hey guys just wondering about some behavior of JS that I am not understanding. The challenge is solved when using the commented line in gray  `// nestedArr.push([`loop${i}`, i]);` but when I try to use the other approach not commented

```
arr.push(`loop${i}`, i);
nestedArr.push(arr);
```

doesn’t work as I thought.

The approach is to first declare an array `arr` and push to it every 5 iterations the string `loop${i}` and the second element index `i`. Next pushing array `arr` into `nestedArr` during 5 iterations. The expected result should arr is pushed 5 times into nestedArr with each push supposedly adding one element at a time within arr. However, as you can see the pushed subarrays arr are all pushed holding 5 elements each 5 times. I was expecting the first iteration when i is 0 the subarray arr pushed to the nestedArr to be holding only one element but is holding already 5 same with other subarrays.

```
[['loop0', 0, 'loop1', 1, 'loop2', 2, 'loop3', 3, 'loop4', 4], ['loop0', 0, 'loop1', 1, 'loop2', 2, 'loop3', 3, 'loop4', 4], ['loop0', 0, 'loop1', 1, 'loop2', 2, 'loop3', 3, 'loop4', 4], ['loop0', 0, 'loop1', 1, 'loop2', 2, 'loop3', 3, 'loop4', 4], ['loop0', 0, 'loop1', 1, 'loop2', 2, 'loop3', 3, 'loop4', 4]]
```

the expected result should be

```
[['loop0', 0], ['loop1', 1], ['loop2', 2], ['loop3', 3], ['loop4', 4]]
```

With each iteration to add one element at the time within subarray arr which is pushed to nestedArr afterwards during the 5 iterations.
Any idea to why?

Comment: You are pushing, inside `nestedArr`, a **reference** of `arr` and adding items to `arr`. The result, so, will be an array with 5 references of `arr`, pointing to the same array in memory (hence the result). For the expected result, just move the `arr` declaration **inside** the loop, so that it will be redeclared each time and the reference pushed to `nestedArr` will always point to a different array in memory (hence 5 different arrays).

Comment: That's makes sense @briosheje, didn't think about that was confusing me a lot. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. As a general rule, please keep in mind that all types other than primitives are passed by reference, so array and objects always are passed by reference in javascript. Keep track of your variables and remember that even logs work by reference, so logging your array while looping would still have logged the same every time.

Comment: I see that's great tip! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize the array `arr` everytime the loop starts again:

```js
const nestedArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let arr = [];
  arr.push(`loop${i}`, i);
  nestedArr.push(arr);
}
console.log(nestedArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Array is an object, hence what you push in final array *nestedArr*, it actually holds the reference of the sub array (*arr* in your case). Now since you are pushing the data in the same sub-array **arr**, reference of it gets updated in the main array everytime and finally when you print the output it conains same object multiple times in the array. To avoid this, you can either use what @Oihane Vázquez suggested or directly push data into the main array like this

```
const nestedArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  nestedArr.push([`loop${i}`, i]);
}

console.log(nestedArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have forgotten to append to arr correctly:

```
const nestedArr = [];
// ADD CODE HERE
let arr = [];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  arr.push([`loop${i}`, i]);
  nestedArr.push(arr);
  // nestedArr.push([`loop${i}`, i]);
}

console.log(nestedArr)
```

look i do an array before to push in arr `arr.push([`loop${i}`, i]);`